# ruby on rails display .c files code on browser as raw text

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, browser, text

I am trying to **display all the contents** of a `.c file` in the browser itself...

So there will be **no need for the user to download** the `.c file`...

i have created a folder in `public/` called `c` which contains `.c files`

But when i direct view any of these files i get asked to download it...

What i want is to **simply display it** as **raw text**...

Answer (score 0):

Try in your view for simplest implementation. Else you can move this function to a controller:

```
<%= File.read(Rails.root.join('public') + "/test.c")
```

Comment: is there any way to **allow all** `.c files` instead of `test.c` only? - edit: also this doesn't seem to work if i put it in the controller